# How to print nested stdclass object array

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I am trying to print values in this nested stdClass Object but I'm having trouble accessing them. How do I print the ID?

```
stdClass Object (
    [AddUserWithLimitResult] => stdClass Object (
        [Header] => stdClass Object ( 
            [Code] => UserAdded
            [Description] => User created
        )
        [ID] => 2243272
        [UserName] => gmail.com
        [FirstName] => sar 
        [LastName] => Sea
        [Email] => gmail.com 
        [SubDomain] => olo
    )
)
```

I tried this:

```
$object->AddUserWithLimitResult->Header->Code->ID;
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: yes, i tried this: $object->AddUserWithLimitResult->Header->Code->ID;

Comment: ^ Add this to your question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you tab out the output it becomes clear that ID is a property of AddUserWithLimitResult

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [AddUserWithLimitResult] => stdClass Object (
        [Header] => stdClass Object (
            [Code] => UserAdded 
            [Description] => User created 
        )
        [ID] => 2243272 
        [UserName] => gmail.com
        [FirstName] => sar 
        [LastName] => Sea 
        [Email] => gmail.com 
        [SubDomain] => olo 
    ) 
)
```

`$object->AddUserWithLimitResult->ID`

Edit: It looks like you updated the question with the tabbed code. When I saw it it was difficult to tell which properties belonged to which objects.