# Accessing array with nested objects

Tags: php

I have an api wrapper i am using that returns something like this

```
object(stdClass)#7 (1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
    ["contactId"]=>
    string(2) "nV"
    ["email"]=>
    string(31) "email@domain.com"
  }
}
```

how do i access the email part with PHP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print nested stdclass object array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29154331/how-to-print-nested-stdclass-object-array)

Comment: I've tried variations of that  $result4->{0} $result4->0 they don't work.

Comment: try `$result4->[0]->email`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast your API returned data to an array.

For example you are saving API returned data in `$result` variable. Cast it to an array.

```
$arrayResult = (array) $result;

echo $arrayResult[0]->email;
```

Try this.